# Map stored procedure results to a custom complex type in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Consider a stored procedure `GetEmployees` which has a `SELECT` statement like

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_EMAIL 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

This stored procedure will have its results mapped to a complex type `GetEmployees_Result`

```
class GetEmployees_Result {
   public int EMP_ID;
   public string EMP_NAME;
   public string EMP_EMAIL;
}
```

Is it possible to map the result of the function import to a different complex type like the one below:

```
class GetEmployeesResult {
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  public string Email;
}
```

Comment: Yes of course - you can create this class `GetEmployeesResult` ahead of time, and then when you add the stored procedure, just pick that it returns a collection of `GetEmployeesResult` that you've already created ...

Comment: As @marc_s pointed you can create custom complex type in the designer yourselves and reuse it.

Comment: yes, this looks like a standard feature. I got it to work. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard feature. You have go to the mapping of the function import and change the result type to the custom type.